# absolute :after pseudo-element not displaying under relative parent

Tags: css, css-position

That's one of these "impossible" CSS moment...
I want to visually add thickness to an element. It's easy, I've done it before and it's pretty nice achieved with an :after pseudo-element.
This pseudo-element has an absolute position. It's parent has a relative position.
Everything is fine, except the pseudo-element is not showing, probably due to a z-index problem. So I put a negative z-index to the pseudo-element and a z-index of 0 to the parent and yes it works... but the content display under the text of its parent, not the background. How can it be possible ?!

You can check it here : https://www.fluidtopics.com/find-and-view/
At the end of the page, there's a violet button "Combine and Publish" that should have a thickness. Play with the z-index of the "a" element and you will see what I mean.

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/sugardaddy/vq2x2uue/

HTML

```
<a href="#" class="ctabutton ctabutton-primary ctabutton-standard "><i class="ft-webicons-coffee"></i>Read Jane’s story</a>
```

CSS

```
.ctabutton-primary::after {
    background-color: #521a4a;
}
.ctabutton::after {
    border-radius: 0.4em;
    bottom: -3px;
    content: "";
    height: 20px;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: -1;
}
.ctabutton-primary, .ctabutton-primary:hover {
    background-color: #852a79;
    color: #ffbb1a !important;
}
.ctabutton, .newsform .mktoForm .mktoButtonWrap.mktoRound .mktoButton {
    border-radius: 0.3em;
    display: inline-block;
    font-weight: 400;
    padding: 0.5em 1em;
    position: relative;
    transition: all 200ms ease-in-out 0s;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Thanks for any help !

EDIT: After a few investigation, setting a negative z-index to the pseudo-element make it disapear, but only in that portion of the page. Check the buttons inside the menus... it works like a charm. So I think it's due to rules on parent elements, but I don't know which one nor what rule.

EDIT 2: Now I really think it's due to nested relative elements. At each level, I add a `z-index:inherit` and now I can see the pseudo-element. But I can only see it when the first level parent has no background (the beige one). In progress...

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

Pseudo elements are actually imaginary tags. So we need to define its 'display' explicitly. Without that, they don't work. So just put

```
    .ctabutton::after, .ctabutton-primary::after {
        display:block;
    }
```

Comment: As the .ctabutton element has a `display:inline-block`, the after element inherit that display. Adding this rule doesn't affect the behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the below mentioned steps for your solution.
 1. wrap this text inside span tag

```
 <span class="cmbSpan">Combine & Publish</span>
```

and add below style in your stylesheet.

```
 .cmbSpan, .ft-webicons-sources{
     z-index: 999;
     position: inherit;
 }
```

and remove z-index form this class `.ctabutton::after{}`

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/stanze/vq2x2uue/2/)

Comment: I did. This produce exactly what it happens actually and I don't want. Check [mine](http://jsfiddle.net/sugardaddy/vq2x2uue/)

Comment: Yes. And that's not what I want because it's what I've got actually and trying to get rid. The content of the :after pseudo-element is under the text and not under the parent. This is what happens now whereas I want this content behind the whole button. But it works in my example, and it doesn't on my website...

Answer (score 0):

Technically, :after & :before are pseudo content for an element which means both of them are part of the content box of an element itself. So, these pseudo element can be stacked only with the content box and not outside the element.

We can go for better solution for this, wrap text "Combine & Publish" &  tag in another wrapper element like , and then position :before beneath the  element.

Here is the sample code,

```css
.ctabutton::after {
  bottom: -3px;
  content: "";
  height: 20px;
  left: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 0.4em;
}
.cont {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<a class="ctabutton ctabutton-primary ctabutton-standard " href="/combine-and-publish/">
  <span class="cont">  <i class="ft-webicons-sources"></i>Combine &amp; Publish </span>
</a>
```

Comment: Sorry but same answer than previously... that doesn't work on my website. The :after content isn't under the background of the parent. I think it's due to another parent element but I don't find how and what.

Answer (score 0):

Well I achieve it with a little modification of my DOM, from the proposal of some answers here.
I use a span around the content of the "button" and give it all the properties to be visually over the pseudo-element.

HTML

```
<a href="#" class="ctabutton ctabutton-primary ctabutton-standard "><span><i class="ft-webicons-coffee"></i>Read Jane’s story</span></a>
```

CSS

```
.ctabutton, 
.newsform .mktoForm .mktoButtonWrap.mktoRound .mktoButton {
    border-radius: 0.3em;
    font-weight: 400;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-transition: all 200ms ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 200ms ease-in-out;
    transition: all 200ms ease-in-out;
}
.ctabutton span {
    display: block;
    padding: 0.5em 1em;
    border-radius: 0.3em;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}

.ctabutton::after {
    bottom: -3px;
    content: "";
    height: 20px;
    left: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 0.4em;
}

.ctabutton-primary span, 
.ctabutton-primary:hover span {
    background-color: #852a79;
    color: #ffbb1a !important;
}

.ctabutton-primary::after { background-color: #521a4a; }
```